# Trying to add throttle control to paralleled API calls in python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, python-decorators

I am using Google places API which has a **query per second** limit of **10**. This means I cannot make more than 10 requests within a second. If we were using Serial execution this wouldn't be an issue as the APIs avg response time is 250 ms, so i will be able to make just 4 calls in a second.

To utilize the entire **10 QPS limit** i used **multithreading** and made parallel API calls. But now i need to control the number of calls that can happen in a second, it should not go beyond **10** (google API starts throwing errors if i cross the limit)

Below is the code that i have so far, I am not able to figure out why the program just gets stuck sometimes or takes alot longer than required.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import random
from threading import Lock
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as pool
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statistics import mean
from ratelimiter import RateLimiter

def make_parallel(func, qps=10):
    lock = Lock()
    threads_execution_que = []
    limit_hit = False
    def qps_manager(arg):
        current_second = time.time()
        lock.acquire()
        if len(threads_execution_que) >= qps or limit_hit:
            limit_hit = True
            if current_second - threads_execution_que[0] <= 1:
                time.sleep(current_second - threads_execution_que[0])
        current_time = time.time()
        threads_execution_que.append(current_time)
        lock.release()

        res = func(arg)

        lock.acquire()
        threads_execution_que.remove(current_time)
        lock.release()
        return res

    def wrapper(iterable, number_of_workers=12):
        result = []
        with pool(max_workers=number_of_workers) as executer:
            bag = {executer.submit(func, i): i for i in iterable}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(bag):
                result.append(future.result())
        return result
    return wrapper

@make_parallel
def api_call(i):
    min_func_time = random.uniform(.25, .3)
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        response = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', timeout=1)
    except Exception as e:
        response = e
    if (time.time() - start_time) - min_func_time < 0:
        time.sleep(min_func_time - (time.time() - start_time))
    return response

api_call([1]*50)
```

Ideally the code should take not more than 1.5 seconds, but currently it is taking about 12-14 seconds.
**The script speeds up to its expected speed as soon as i remove the QPS manager logic.**

Please do suggest what i am doing wrong and also, if there is any package available already which does this mechanism out of the box.

Comment: Your code has syntax and logic errors. Please fix indentation: `return wrapper` is at the global scope. `wrapper` is not used anywhere and `make_parallel` simply can't work since it returns None

Comment: Sorry, fixed the indentation. The code should make sense now.

Comment: Could you clarify what `qps_manager` is doing? It is not called anywhere, so I don't understand why it is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [ratelimit](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/) does just that:

```
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry

@make_parallel
@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=10, period=1)
def api_call(i):
    try:
        response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", timeout=1)
    except Exception as e:
        response = e
    return response
```

EDIT: I did some testing and it looks like `@sleep_and_retry` is a little too optimistic, so just increase the period a little, to 1.2 second:

```
s = datetime.now()
api_call([1] * 50)
elapsed_time = datetime.now() - s
print(elapsed_time > timedelta(seconds=50 / 10))
```

Comment: I did test it in a few scenarios, the QPS limiting is happening!! :)

But, We are wrapping make_parallel along with ratelimit decorators, wouldn't this mean we are rate limiting each thread and not the entire process as one??

Comment: @Scarface, not if we decorate in correct order. The input to `@make_parallel` is the result of previous decorators, so `@make_parallel` takes the function that was rate limited, and run it in parallel.

Comment: Thank you, It solved what I was looking for and also cleared some of my questions.